# Break a large file into smaller pieces

Tags: command-line, split

How do I break a large, **+4GB** file into smaller files of about **500MB** each.

And how do I **re-assemble** them again to get the original file?

Comment: text line-wise version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016894/easy-way-to-split-a-large-text-file

Comment: Related: [How to split larger files into smaller parts?](https://askubuntu.com/q/54579/78223)

Answer (score 92, accepted):

You can use [*split*](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/split-invocation.html) and *cat*.

For example something like

```
$ split --bytes 500M --numeric-suffixes --suffix-length=3 foo foo.
```

(where the input filename is `foo` and the last argument is the output prefix).  This will create files like `foo.000 foo.001` ...

The same command with short options:

```
$ split -b 100k -d -a 3 foo foo
```

You can also specify "--line-bytes" if you wish it to split on line boundaries instead of just exact number of bytes.

For re-assembling the generated pieces again you can use e.g.:

```
$ cat foo.* > foo_2
```

(assuming that the shell sorts the results of shell globbing - and the number of parts does not exceed the system dependent limit of arguments)

You can compare the result via:

```
$ cmp foo foo_2
$ echo $?
```

(which should output 0)

Alternatively, you can use a combination of find/sort/xargs to re-assemble the pieces:

```
$ find -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'foo.*'  | sort | xargs cat > foo_3
```

Comment: Try this command: `man split cat md5sum`

Comment: When assembling, I recommend `cat foo.{000..NNN}` where `NNN` is the last expected piece. That way you get an error message if one of the pieces is missing. But note that `-d` to get numeric suffixes is specific to GNU split; on other platforms you have to make do with `foo.aaa`, `foo.aab`, etc.

Comment: And bear in mind that, for `split`, KB = 1000, K = 1024, MB = 1000*1000, M = 1024*1024 etc.

Comment: Shouldn't this `... cat > foo_3` be `... cat >>foo_3`?

Comment: @alk, no, it should not. The part that `xargs` sees as arguments (and thus potentially forks/execs multiple times) is `cat`. The part `> foo_3` is interpreted by the shell (the shell creates the output redirection for the xargs process). Thus, everything is ok.

Comment: Ah yes, sure. Temp brain laps ... sry.

Comment: If you decide to ease pain by using a utility. `rar` and `7zip` are often used in making such splits easier to reassemble cross-platform

Answer (score 4):

You can also do this with Archive Manager if you prefer a GUI. Look under 'Save->Other Options->Split into volumes of'.

Comment: i tagged it 'command-line', but thanks for the answer :)